# When I install the IRI (IOTA reference implementation), I encouter some problems

Tags: python, java, maven, iota

I have installed Maven 3.8.3 and Java version 17 in my 'Windows' computer, but when I want to install the IRI (IOTA reference implementation) (https://github.com/iotaledger/iri), I try

```
git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/iri
cd iri
mvn clean compile 
mvn package
```

When I tried `mvn clean compile`, it shows `BUILD SUCCESS`. But when I try `mvn package`, I got a lot of errors.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project iri: There are test failures. 
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\Mask_project\Code\Smart_Bin\iri\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "D:\Software\Java\bin\java -javaagent:C:\\Users\\Liann\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\Mask_project\\Code\\Smart_Bin\\iri\\target\\jacoco.exec -jar C:\Users\Liann\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2232304534365969087\surefirebooter4892105985596447277.jar C:\Users\Liann\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2232304534365969087 2021-10-19T21-25-14_249-jvmRun1 surefire5424955682352844069tmp surefire_010893959374131254731tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "D:\Software\Java\bin\java -javaagent:C:\\Users\\Liann\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\Mask_project\\Code\\Smart_Bin\\iri\\target\\jacoco.exec -jar C:\Users\Liann\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2232304534365969087\surefirebooter4892105985596447277.jar C:\Users\Liann\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire2232304534365969087 2021-10-19T21-25-14_249-jvmRun1 surefire5424955682352844069tmp surefire_010893959374131254731tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:972)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I am a begainner in IOTA things, especially coding. Would anyone please help me with that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: First upgrade the plugins you are using (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) furthermore why do you call `mvn clean compile` and afterwards `mvn package` please go `mvn clean package` that's sufficient and prevents dublications...

Comment: Also the given project on github is archived and replaced with another project on Github which is implemented in Go...

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answers. Thank you very much! 
I'll try both this old version IRI and new version!